# Signon types for a .net web application

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Other than forms authentication, what are other common forms of authentication that an application should ideally support?

Is it just active directory or is LDAP a must also?

Comment: This is very similar to your earlier question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791466/is-supporting-active-directory-in-a-web-application-difficult-when-currently-buil

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you only need to support one kind of authentication.

With forms authentication, you have to provide a database table containing user names and passwords. And you should provide the ability for users to change their passwords, etc. This is all made easier with the Membershp provider.

If you have the option of using Active Directory or another LDAP, that removes the burden from you of establishing logins and maintaining them. If that choice is available to you, I'd recommend using it.

Answer (score 1):

Likely you only want to support one form of authentication.  Here are a couple other than Forms authentication that you can use.

- Windows Authentication: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998358.aspx
- OpenId: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/4b3c7c9b-fe80-4e6e-a34e-0e9efed5c575/integrate-openid-authenti.aspx

Comment: with a CMS, clients want AD support also don't you think? especially for intranet usage.